# Return type of closure in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, closures, function-pointers, return-type

I am trying to learn closures in C++. This example works:

```
auto add_n(int n) {
    return [=](int x) -> int {
        return x + n;
    };
};
auto add_3 = add_n(3);
add_3(5); //8
```

What type is add_n expecting out? I would expect to be able to use a function pointer that takes in an int and returns an int as the return type?

```
typedef int (*fptr)(int);
fptr add_n(int n) {
    return [=](int x) -> int {
        return x + n;
    }; 
};
```

Additionally, would anything else need to be done if I am working with templates instead? Thank you!

Comment: The return value of `add_n` is some compiler-generated class type that cannot be easily named (but can be aliased via `decltype`). It can't be a plain function pointer - there's no space in that to store the captured `n`.

Comment: Lambdas (or closures) have unnameable types. Normally you wouldn't be able to specify the type explicitly (unless the lambda happens to have no capture and your return type is the corresponding function pointer type).

Comment: *"if I am working with templates instead?"*, Not sure where and how you would add template, but from what I think of possible use, I don't see extra work for that.

Comment: Thank you to all! Without the capture it allows that syntax, but doesn't seem to be too useful... @Jarod42
I was thinking something like
`template <typename num>
auto add_n(num n)`

vs
`template <typename num>
typedef num (*fptr)(num);
fptr add_3() {`

but with the limitation on the capture the 2nd would be pretty useless.

Comment: The only rule is that a lambda that doesn't capture anything can be implicitly converted to a function pointer. But that doesn't mean it _is_ a function pointer. And if it does capture something, well, no such luck.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel What do you mean when you say it doesn't have to be a function pointer?  With
`int foo() {return 1;};
cout << foo //address
cout << foo() << " " << (*foo)() //calling foo `
It seems to act like a pointer, would there be anything wrong with thinking of it this way?

Comment: When I say a lambda doesn't have to be a function pointer, and you reply by showing me something that's not a lambda, that doesn't seem to me like you understood my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each lambda has its own unnamed types, so you cannot replace `auto` by its real type.

Lambda with capture cannot be converted to function pointer.